# Random PHP is not picking one at random, not displaying information

Tags: php, random

cannot seem to understand why the bottom random isn't working, it was working before - Any ideas?

```
<?php 
$num = Rand (1,2,3);
// Based on random Case Number Echos that code
switch ($num) {
case 1:
echo 'CONTENT1';
break;
case 2:
echo 'CONTENT2';
break;
case 3:
echo 'CONTENT3';
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: So you are using a function that doesn't work as expected. Did you [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) before asking? Did you think about what you are doing here? If this were OK, how would you request a random number between 1 and 1000?

Comment: @Jon -  your feedback is hardly helpful here, I understand PHP but have been working on things so hard lately, that I turned blind to this one problem. I went quickly through the manual but as said at times, you get a block.

Comment: The time it took you to cry about my question, would be the time that you could answer it, be civil and in fact it was the answer answered by JunM that helped me noticed a number of problems.

Comment: Another way to see things is that by answering this question I would encourage the next person who calls a function with the wrong number of arguments (or who does not bother to RTFM) to ask as well. Even if I accept your explanation (which I find rather difficult for obvious reasons) that does not invalidate the rationale behind the original comment. Finally, it's also really hard to accept advice on being civil from someone who calls you a crybaby in the same sentence.

Comment: @Jon Well the fact that Stackoverflow didn't have an answer anything close to this may deem the question I asked reasonable - regardless of me scamming through the manual or not. My problem is fixed, so stackoverflow did its job.

Comment: StackOverflow also doesn't have an answer to the question "why `echo 'foo'` does not print 'bar'?". Do you think it should?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rand()` function should only have two parameters min and max.

So if you want to random 1,2 and 3, it it should be rand(1,3)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Usage:

```
int rand ( void )
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and getrandmax(). If you want a random number between 1 and 3 (inclusive), for example, use

```
rand(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

always remember when dealing with switch use `default` as well

```
default :
    echo 'default message';
     break;
```

and can use `rand(lowerlimit,upperlimit)` or `RAND(lowerlimit,upperlimit)` php built in functions are not case sensative.